# How do i track the changes made to a DXP file by a Spotfire Developer Analyst

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a requirement to track changes like Deleting; a page , table , column , adding; page, column, table, adding bar chart etc. Basically i want as much information as possible. Does Action Log support this ?

Answer (score 2):

The action log does not track this much detail.  I am fairly certain there is not a way to track this much detail.

Comment: correct. you can see specifically what actions are recoreded in the Action Log by using the Spotfire configurator GUI and/or looking up the documentation.